How do I change the color of text in Quasar?
I tried
<p color="primary">foo</p>

and
<p style="color: primary">foo</p>

but neither works. How do I make my text colour primary?

<p class="text-primary">foo</p> Ref - https://quasar.dev/style/color-palette#using-as-css-classes

instead of
<p style="color: primary">foo</p>

try this
<p style="color: primary;">foo</p>

or you can use something like this:
<style>
    .primary-color {
        color: primary;
    }
</style>

<p class="primary-color">foo</p>

how ever  if you have any custom color code you have to replace it like this
.primary-color {
    color: #ffffff; /* Replace #ff0000  */
}


I think James Ashok's comment is the right answer

As per James Ashok's comment:
<p class="text-primary">foo</p>

